# How to paginate search results?

Tags: pagination, search

What’s the best way to paginate search results?

I was using

```
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
```

and then

```
{% paginate craft.entries.search(query).section('…').limit(…).order('…') as entries %}
```

but the pagination links (paginate.prevUrl and paginate.nextUrl) don’t contain the query.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`{{ paginate.nextUrl }}?q={{ query }}` did the trick with this setup.

Answer (score 3):

I think this will work

```
{{ paginate.prevUrl }}?search=' ~ (craft.request.getParam('search'))
```

Comment: Thanks. I used {{ paginate.nextUrl }}?q={{ query }} and that worked with my setup.