# Searching a specific section by four different types of parameters?

Tags: relations, search, ajax

I'll do my best to explain this.

I have a Portfolio of companies, which I have as a structure, that I need to be able to filter/search through by using up to four different parameters.

1. **Keyword** - a basic search field that a user can type into
2. **Industry** - a category field
3. **Company Status** - a dropdown field
4. **Board Members** - a relation to a different structure

I know how to search these individually but I'm not quite sure how to use any combo of these all at once. Whether that be using a keyword and industry to search, all four items to search, maybe just by industry and board members, or maybe just by industry.

Below is what I have so far. Hoping someone will be able to point me in the right direction or help me piece this together.

**This handles the search**

```html
{# What is being searched #}
{% set portfolio = craft.entries.section('portfolio') %}

{# Potential Query Strings #}
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{% set industryParam = craft.request.getParam('industry') %}
{% set statusParam = craft.request.getParam('status') %}
{% set boardMemberParam = craft.request.getParam('boardMember') %}

{# Related to Industry and/or Board Member #}
{% set industry = craft.categories.group('industries').slug(industryParam).first %}

{# Here's where I'm not sure how to combine the relatedTo for the industry, status, and/or board members #}
{% set relationParam = industryParam ? {targetElement: industry} : '' %}

{% set entries = portfolio.relatedTo(relationParam).search(query) %}

{# Probably best to not use search, as it's slower than relatedTo, so I commented this out. #}
{# .search('companyStatus::"' ~ statusParam ~ '"') #}

{# Spit out the entries #}
{% if entries|length %}

  {% for entry in entries %}
    <article class="portfolio-item grid-3">
      <a class="portfolio-item-content" href="{{ entry.url }}">
        <h3 class="portfolio-item-title">{{ entry.title }}</h3>
      </a>
    </article>
  {% endfor %}

{% else %} {# If nothing matches the search criteria #}

  <p>Sorry, no results.</p>

{% endif %}
```

**Stripped down version of where the user sets the parameters**

```html
<form action="{{ url('portfolio') }}">
  <h3 class="sidebar-title">Filter by Keyword</h3>
  <input type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search">

  <h3 class="sidebar-title">Filter by Industry</h3>
  <select class="fancy" name="industry">
    <option value="">All Industries</option>

    {# Only get categories that are being used. #}
    {# This will definitely need some cache tags. #}
    {% set categories = craft.categories.group('industries').order('title asc') %}
    {% set entriesWithCategories = craft.entries.relatedTo(categories) %}
    {% set categoriesInUse = craft.categories.relatedTo(entriesWithCategories) %}

    {% for category in categoriesInUse %}
      <option value="{{ category.slug }}">{{ category.title }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>

  <h3 class="sidebar-title">Filter by Status</h3>
  <select class="fancy" name="status">
    <option value="">All Statuses</option>
    <option value="active">Active</option>
    <option value="past">Past</option>
  </select>

  <h3 class="sidebar-title">Filter by Board Member</h3>
  <select class="fancy" name="boardMember">
    <option value="">All Board Memebers</option>
    {% set team = craft.entries.section('team') %}
    {% for member in team %}
      <option value="{{ member.slug }}">{{ member.title }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>

  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

And if possible, how would I do this with AJAX? This can come later, initial search function is 100% okay. I know I could do the the AJAX filter completely on the Front-End but there's potential that the client will want to eventually add pagination if they start adding a bunch of companies to their portfolio.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Zack - I'll take a look at the search in a bit, but as for the AJAX, you'll be able to do that using Routes and the built in [pagination](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/paginate) template tag. Separate that into a new question once this one is resolved to give it some room to be answered :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks @aberkie. And separating the AJAX is definitely a good idea. I'll see if I can take a shot at it once the "basic" search is taken care of. Looking forward to seeing what you come up with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One method is to build your params before performing the search.

```twig
{# set base params #}
{% set params = {
    section: 'portfolio',
    limit: null
} %}
{% set relatedParams = ['and'] %}

{# status #}
{% if craft.request.getParam('status') %}
    {% set status = craft.request.getParam('status') %}
    {% set params = params|merge({'companyStatus':status}) %}
{% endif %}

{# industry #}
{% if craft.request.getParam('industry') %}
    {% set category = craft.categories.group('industries').slug(craft.request.getParam('industry')).first %}
    {% set relatedParams = relatedParams|merge([{ targetElement:category }]) %}
{% endif %}

{# board member #}
{% if craft.request.getParam('boardMember') %}
    {% set boardMember = craft.entries.section('team').slug(craft.request.getParam('boardMember')).first %}
    {% set relatedParams = relatedParams|merge([{ targetElement:boardMember }]) %}
{% endif %}

{# add relatedParams to params #}
{% if relatedParams|length > 1 %}
    {% set params = params|merge({'relatedTo':relatedParams}) %}
{% endif %}

{# perform search #}
{% set searchParams = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{% set entries = craft.entries(params).search(searchParams|trim) %}

{# display results #}
{% for entry in entries %}
    {{ entry.title }}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

To AJAX load results you would place this in another template and load it dynamically with jquery. See [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/search-contact-person-plugin-via-ajax/4415#4415) for an example.

To paginate the results you will need to submit your form as "GET" and append the query to your nextPage and prevPage links. See [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6655/search-results-pagination-with-multiple-form-fields) for an example.

Comment: You should avoid passing a single `['and']` to the `relatedTo` param (→ ["Users relatedTo multiple categories"](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/5107/125)).

Comment: @DouglasMcDonald appreciate the response. This method definitely makes sense to me. Unfortunately it's throwing a template error at: `{% set params = params|merge(['status':status]) %}` and `{% set params = params|merge(['relatedTo':relatedParams]) %}`

**"An array element must be followed by a comma. Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ":" ("punctuation" expected with value ",")"**

A comma there doesn't make sense to me. I also tried it for the hell of it and the search doesn't work with commas there. So I'm not sure what I should do to fix the template error.

Comment: Try `{% set params = params|merge({'relatedTo':relatedParams}) %}`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Awesome, that fixed the template error. The only thing not working now is the status param. It doesn't throw an error or anything it just doesn't filter anything. Seeing if I can fix it. I'll update this comment if I get it.

Comment: I think that the reason 'status' is not working is that there is a craft parameter called [status](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#status). Possible values are 'live', 'pending', 'expired', 'disabled', and null. You may need to rename that variable.

Comment: That definitely seems have have been it. I've changed it to `companyStatus` and all it working correctly. I was also able to modify this to work with AJAX based off the links you provided. Thanks for all the help Doug!

Comment: Great! Glad you got it working.